# Improper usage of calcHist

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

My aim is to generate a histogram for a gray-scale image. The code I used is :

```
Mat img = imread("leeds-castle.jpg",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat hst;
int hstsize = 256;
float ranges[] = { 0,256 };
float *hstrange = { ranges };
calcHist( img, 1,0, Mat(), hst, 1, &hstsize,&hstrange,true,false);
int hst_w = 512, hst_h = 400;
int bin_w = cvRound((double)hst_w / 256);
Mat histimg(hst_w, hst_h, CV_8U);
normalize(hst, hst, 0, histimg.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
{
    line(histimg, Point(bin_w*(i - 1), hst_h - cvRound(hst.at<float>(i - 1))), Point(bin_w*i, hst_h - cvRound(hst.at<float>(i))), 2, 8, 0);
}
imshow("Histogram", histimg);
```

The only error is the usage of `calcHist()` function. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: error is  "C2665 'cv::calcHist': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types"

Answer (score 0):

See the comment above calcHist to identify the correct usage:

```
// original image
Mat img = imread("leeds-castle.jpg",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
// NOTE: check if img.channels is equal to 1

// histogram
Mat hst;

// number of bins
int hstsize = 256;
float ranges[] = { 0,256 };
float *hstrange = { ranges };

// parameters for histogram calculation
bool uniform = true; 
bool accumulate = false;

// calculate histogram
// the '&' was missing here
calcHist( &img, 1,0, Mat(), hst, 1, &hstsize,&hstrange,true,false);
```

Comment: Could you describe what changes you made in the code and why this fixes the OP's problem? As it stands, your post is less an answer and more a game of Where's Waldo.

Comment: @beaker: I am sure those who (can) read the comments can find the answer without playing Where's Waldo :-)

Comment: Cutting out a third of the code and directing attention to the line that was changed helped somewhat, but code only answers are generally considered less helpful than those including an explanation of why and how the updated code works. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290231/is-it-wrong-to-ask-for-an-explanation-of-how-why-the-code-works-in-code-only-ans and many others in meta.